# Eclipse ctrl+/ used to // comment an entire section of Java. How do I get it back?

Tags: java, eclipse

I really miss ctrl+/ for // commenting entire sections of java and javascript. The most recent downloads of Eclipse have apparently broken this feature. How do I get it back?

Comment: This questions seems programming related, but not a programming question.

Comment: @Taplar Questions about [_"software tools commonly used by programmers"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are on-topic.

Comment: This still works fine for Java. Javascript is a different editor.

Answer (score 2):

I have Eclipse 2020-06 and **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** worked for me. Code goes from

```
System.out.println("hello");
System.out.println("world");
```

to

```
// System.out.println("hello");
// System.out.println("world");
```

and back.

Comment: @fivedogit Sorry I'm confused then, what do you want to do?

Comment: @fivedogit That's what happens when I do Ctrl+Shift+C.

Comment: Oh wait, you're right. That works! Thanks! Wonder why they changed it?

Comment: I am using Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0). Both `Ctrl+/` and `Ctrl+Shift+C` are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a third-party plugin you installed is overriding your key shortcut for Ctrl+/ . You can just go to Window > Preferences... Then expand General > Keys and search for "toggle comment". You can then set it to whatever you need, like Ctrl+/ (that's the default for me). Also, make sure the column "When" is "Editing Java Source". See ScreenShot.[image]